# Change value of a field before/during Max statement

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

To find max grade for multiple student enrollment records, alpha grades like KG and PS are showing up as max even though grade 12 would be "higher".  Is there a way to set non-numeric grades to 00 so they would not show as max (unless the student only enrolled in a non-numeric grade). I tried the following and can't even get it to compile.  The compiler doesn't like the "When not in".Thank You in advance for any solution that will work.  If a student enrolled for the last 10 years from KG thru 09...I want to see 09 as the max grade level.

```
DECLARE @grade char(2);
SET @grade='00'

Select
SD.[Student_Number] as [Student_Number],
Max (SE.[Grade_Level]) as [Grade_Level],
        CASE SE.[Grade_Level]
            when not in ('01','02','03','04','05','06','07',''08',''09','10','11','12') 
            then @grade 
            else (SE.[Grade_Level])
         End
From
Student_DemographicsCube as SD WITH (NOLOCK),
Student_EnrollmentCube as SE WITH (NOLOCK) 
Where
SD.[Student_ID] = SE.[Student_ID] 
Group By
    SD.[Student_Number]
Order By
SD.[Student_Number]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query has a few issues. First, you should use explicit JOIN syntax. Second, the `CASE` expression and `Max()` syntax isn't formatted right.  Try using:

```
Select
  SD.[Student_Number] as [Student_Number],
  Max(CASE when SE.[Grade_Level] not in ('01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12') 
           then @grade 
           else SE.[Grade_Level]
         End) as [Grade_Level]
From Student_DemographicsCube as SD WITH (NOLOCK)
Inner Join Student_EnrollmentCube as SE WITH (NOLOCK) 
  ON SD.[Student_ID] = SE.[Student_ID] 
Group By SD.[Student_Number]
Order By SD.[Student_Number];
```

You'll notice that I moved the `WHERE SD.[Student_ID] = SE.[Student_ID]` to the `INNER JOIN` to be explicit that you are joining the tables.  Then the syntax for a `CASE` expression is `CASE WHEN <some condition> THEN <something> ELSE <something else> END` which get placed inside of the `MAX()` aggregate function.  This should fix the syntax issue you had.

Comment: Excellent...I used your answer and it is now working as expected !  Thank You !